# matplotlib.font_manager debug messages in log file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I want to log the progress of my optimization in a log file, but my log file gets filled with stuff from the matplotlib font manager, e.g.:

```
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: Matching :family=sans-serif:style=normal:variant=normal:weight=normal:stretch=normal:size=10.0.)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeThreeSym' (STIXSizThreeSymBol.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'cmmi10' (cmmi10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeTwoSym' (STIXSizTwoSymReg.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'cmsy10' (cmsy10.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans' (DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf) oblique normal bold normal>) = 1.335)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' (DejaVuSansMono-BoldOblique.ttf) oblique normal bold normal>) = 11.335)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'STIXSizeOneSym' (STIXSizOneSymReg.ttf) normal normal regular normal>) = 10.05)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' (DejaVuSansMono.ttf) normal normal 400 normal>) = 10.05)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans' (DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 0.33499999999999996)
DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(<Font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' (DejaVuSansMono-Bold.ttf) normal normal bold normal>) = 10.335)
```

I'm using the logger as follows:

```
import logging

logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(filename='logfile.log',level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s)')

def objective(x):

    obj=model(x)
    logger.debug('objective = {}'.format(obj))

    return obj
```

How can I keep matplotlib from crapping all over my log file?

Comment: Try removing `level=logging.DEBUG` from the `basicConfig` and adding a line below that is `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`. Does that work?

Comment: no, that did not work :(

Comment: I'm a little surprised that doesn't work for you. Are you able to make a minimal reproducible example that we can just copy and paste to see the problem?

Comment: your solution works. I thought there was a new log file at every run, but it is just appending the new logs to the old file. once I deleted the file, it was all good :)

Comment: but why? this sounds like a bug.... is it a feature?

Comment: If you want to continue to use `basicConfig`, you can also change the logging level of `matplotlib.font_manager`: `logging.getLogger('matplotlib.font_manager').setLevel(logging.WARNING)`

Comment: ... or set all of matplotlib to warning level: `logging.getLogger('matplotlib').setLevel(logging.WARNING)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution was provided by tomjn:

`level=logging.DEBUG` from the `basicConfig` was removed and in the line below `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`
was added. So that makes

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Comment: How to specifically remove the logs of font_manager ?

Comment: Try this:

`logging.getLogger('matplotlib.font_manager').disabled = True`

Answer (score 0):

*With full credit to @SimoX:*

Add this line to suppress all that garbage from `matplotlib.font_manager`:

```py
logging.getLogger('matplotlib.font_manager').disabled = True
```